# How to set defualt value for primeng autocomplete <p-autocomplete>

Tags: angular, primeng

I tried below but didn't worked.

Added below to `<p-autocomplete>`

`[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`      and `[(ngModel)]="sampleModelData"`

and in .ts file  added

```
this.sampleModelData='ramesh';
```

even I tried setting as below in .ts file but this too didn't work.
`(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('sampleModelData')).value='ramesh123';`

How to resolve issue

Comment: I tried this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-oxflpo and everything is fine for me. Could you describe more or show your example which does not work?

Answer (score 1):

you need to get a reference to the autocomplete component that you can access to the input native element

```js
  @ViewChild('autoItems', { static: true }) public autoItems: AutoComplete; // 

  setAutoValue() {

    this.selectedValue = {label:'Apple' , value:'apple'}; 
    this.autoItems.inputEL.nativeElement.value = this.selectedValue.label; // 
  }
```

*template*

```html
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" field="label" [suggestions]="result" 
   (completeMethod)="search($event)"#autoItems>
</p-autoComplete>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-autocomplate)